# CMake could not find OpenCV library like cv.h

Tags: opencv, cmake, shared-libraries

I'd wanted to run the project in Ubuntu PC, but I received an error.

When I ran the following code;

```
make
```

And, There is a error in following;

```
      asiye@asiye:~/Desktop/cmfd_framework/build$ make
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target common
[  8%] Built target common
[ 10%] Building CXX object ground_truth_db/CMakeFiles/cmfdgt.dir/command_ground_truth.cpp.o
/home/asiye/Desktop/cmfd_framework/ground_truth_db/command_ground_truth.cpp:10:10: fatal error: cv.h: No such file or directory
   10 | #include "cv.h"
      |          ^~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: * [ground_truth_db/CMakeFiles/cmfdgt.dir/build.make:76: ground_truth_db/CMakeFiles/cmfdgt.dir/command_ground_truth.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: * [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:205: ground_truth_db/CMakeFiles/cmfdgt.dir/all] Error 2
make: * [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

I think Cmake could not find OpenCV library but why ?

Could you explain to me if there is another way to address this problem?

Best Regards,

Comment: no, it's a different problem. cv.h is from the long time deprecated opencv 1.0 C-API. so, you're trying with stone-age code. reconsider using that, please, it's probably umaintainable

Comment: opencv 4.x does no more install any C-API headers.

Comment: first of all thank you for the reply, Sorry but, I don't know how to change cv.h header to header of OpenCV4.x. Could you explain in detail ?

Comment: could you point us to the code you're trying to use ?

Comment: In literature, there is a paper named Copy-Move forgery detection based on PatchMatch'' IEEE International Conference on Image Processing, October 2014. All the scripts are written in perl by authors. They require the CMFD framework of Pattern Recognition Lab. Here is framework link :
  http://www5.cs.fau.de/research/software/copy-move-forgery-detection/

      I wanted to run the script dataset of that paper.

Comment: There is a function named cvPoint2D32f but It is an CApi, How can I convert to appropriate C++. Code block is like that;

`cvLogPolar( &val, &logp,  cvPoint2D32f(dat.cols/2, dat.rows/2), optiM, CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS);`

Comment: you could still try to `#include <opencv2/core/core_c.h>` instead or fall back to some older opencv version (pre 4.x). otherwise: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga49481ab24fdaa0ffa4d3e63d14c0d5e4

Comment: Hello, Thank you for help. But, Source code is not mine, I just want to result images  of their codes but There is a no way rather than running stone-age code. So now, I have another error. If you explain me I will be appreciate to you.

`fmt.cxx: In member function ‘virtual void Fmt::computeOne(const cv::Mat&, int)’:
fmt.cxx:55:17: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘cv::InputArray’ {aka ‘const cv::_InputArray&’} from expression of type ‘cv::Mat*’
cv::warpPolar( &val, &logp, cv::Point2f(mag.cols/2,mag.rows/2), optiM, cv::WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS);`

Comment: we cannot debug things we cannot see, sadly. but why is there a pointer to Mat ?? that looks bad / wrong

Comment: can you share the cmake you run ?

Comment: Now I have new error.

`fatal error: opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp: No such file or directory` 

And, I ran that code;

`sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:jeff250/opencv`

following error;

`Err:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release 404  Not Found 
Err:11 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates Release                               
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jeff250/opencv/ubuntu focal Release 404  Not Found 
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xqms/opencv-nonfree/ubuntu focal Release 404  Not Found`

Answer (score 1):

Cmake Dosyası burada   [Yunus Temurlenk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11048887/yunus-temurlenk)

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(Vole)

set(Vole_CMFD ON)
set(Vole_CMFD_Ground_Truth ON)
set(Vole_Shell ON)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)


include(VoleHelperMacros)
include(VoleModuleMacros)

if(WIN32)
    add_definitions(-DNOMINMAX) # prevents min- and max-macro brainf*ck in VS 2003
endif(WIN32)

# Global options
option(VOLE_CMAKE_DEBUG_OUTPUT "Show additonal cmake debug output." OFF)
mark_as_advanced(VOLE_CMAKE_DEBUG_OUTPUT)
option(VOLE_CHECK_DEPENDENCIES "Do additional dependency check with nice error messages." ON)
mark_as_advanced(VOLE_CHECK_DEPENDENCIES)
option(VOLE_SINGLE_TARGETS "Build single targets for each command." OFF)
set(VOLE_MODULE_DIRECTORIES "" CACHE STRING "Semicolon-separated list of module directories for vole, e.g. the forensics or the color code.")
# maybe there is a better place for these two options:
option(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS "Suppress searching in system paths or other locations outside of BOOST_ROOT." OFF)
set(BOOST_ROOT "" CACHE STRING "The preferred installation prefix for searching for Boost. Set this if the module has problems finding the proper Boost installation.")

# Global variables
set(VOLE_PACKAGE_LIST "" CACHE INTERNAL "Package list" FORCE)
set(VOLE_EXTERNAL_SUBDIRECTORIES "" CACHE INTERNAL "External subdirectories" FORCE)
set(VOLE_MODULE_LIST "" CACHE INTERNAL "Module list" FORCE)

include(VoleFindPackages)
# include(VoleFindExternalModules)

add_subdirectory(common core/common)

include_directories(common shell cmfd ground_truth_db)
add_subdirectory(cmfd cmfd)
add_subdirectory(ground_truth_db ground_truth_db)
add_subdirectory(shell core/shell)

include(VoleCheckDependencies)

INCLUDE("CMakeModules/TargetDoc.cmake" OPTIONAL)
```

Comment: Could you detail more the solution? It's just a little confused. Welcome!